# Incremental data from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, cloud

I have a number of identical local postgreSql databases (identical in structure - not data) on several laptops that have intermittant access to internet. Records are being added to each DB daily. So Branch A,B,C each with a local Postgresql database. I would like all records from A,B,C in each table in a cloud Database.Also A,B,C data is separate - there is no overlap - A doesnt change B, or C etc. There are no duplicated unique keys.

NEED: I would like to collect all this data on a cloud based database by adding daily incremental data to a single cloud databse - so I can query the whole consolidated data using SQL and pull reports as needed.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if two users update the same record with different values while offline?

Comment: Thanks bobflux - that will not happen as each user has diffrent data.- sorry -  when I said identical - I meant identical strucrure. Each record has a unique key. So I will be aggregating that data.

Comment: Do you want to transfer the entire row if it was modified, or is there a large column like TEXT or BYTEA that is seldom modified but would make the amount of data much larger than it needs, which would justify special treatment?

Comment: Thanks again bobflux - yes entire row if modified. Actually old data will be infrequently modified and volume will be low. Just new data added daily in each local Table. So identify new data since last push and send those to online DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want logical replication from each laptop to the cloud server.  The problem there might be that contact must be made by the replica to each of the masters, so when your laptops are online, they would need to have predictable IP addresses so that they can be reached.

Maybe the best way around this is with a reverse SSH tunnel.  On the central replica, you would tell it to subscribe to a publication hosted on some non-standard port on localhost.  With a different port reserved for each laptop.  So, for example, 9997, 9998, and 9999.

Then when each laptop has connectivity, it could run something like:

```
ssh rajb@1centralserver.example.com -R9999:localhost:5432 -f -N -T
```

This establishes an ssh connection to the central server (requiring a password, or private key, or however you have ssh set up) and sends instructions to the central server that whenever someone connects to port 9999 on the central server it should really send that connection back over ssh tunnel and hook it up to port 5432 (the default postgres server port) of the laptop.

For initially setting things up and debugging, you might want to omit the `-f -N -T`.  That way, in addition to setting up the tunnel, you also get an interactive ssh session you can use for monitoring things.

Once the central service notices the connection is available, it will start downloading changes since the last time it could connect.  When there is no connection, you will get a lot of nuisance messages to the log file as it checks each server every ~5 seconds to see if it is available.

From each laptop's perspective, the connection is coming from within, so the replication connection will use whatever authentication is set up or 127.0.0.1 or ::1, not the authentication set up for the actual remote IP.

Comment: Thanks jjanes - Is there no way for the laptop when its online to contact the cloud server and send the data? I doubt I can get static ip addresses.

Comment: OK I looked this up and this is nearly what I am looking for. Here A,B,C would be Publishers and Cloud Database would be a subscriber. This would work fine if A,B,C were always online. sadly that's not the case. If only the Publisher could *send* to subscriber this would solve it.

Comment: When each comes online, it could connect to the central one and do an ALTER  SUBSCRIPTION to update its ip address.  That won't help with NAT/firewalls though.  I don't know of a way to have it use a connection created by the publisher.

Comment: Thanks again jjanes - Looks promising. They will be connecting using wifi from their mobiles - google says mobile wifi normally NAT. I am not particularly wedded to Postgresql - is there any other free-ish (we are a charity) database than can solve - must be a common situation in developing places where net is flaky! Currently aggregating googlesheets but its a royal pain.

Comment: Thanks jjanes. I am grateful for the thought and effort you have put into this. I am a newbie on all this but where there is will there is a way!  I thought this must be a very common requirement but seems not.